# Shopify List Blog Tags

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to create a page in Shopify that loops through all the tags assigned to blog articles in a blog called 'Recipes', and simply list them all.

This seems simple, but my page is not outputting any tags.

-I have a blog created called 'Recipes'

-I have blog posts assigned to the 'Recipes' blog, and each one has a different tag assigned.

-I created a template (page.blogtags.liquid), and assigned that template to a page called 'Blog Tags'

My code for page.blogtags.liquid is as follows:

```
<div id=”blog-tags”>
    <!– Loops over all the tags used in Recipes blog –>
    {% for tag in blogs[recipes].tags %}
        <h2>{{ tag }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The page is outputting the div, but it contains nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing quotes around `recipes`. Currently, Liquid is treating `recipes` as a variable and since it is undefined, it silently fails. All you needs is `'recipes'` or `"recipes"` to specify that you want to access blogs property named `recipes`. So the code would become

```
<div id=”blog-tags”>
    <!– Loops over all the tags used in Recipes blog –>
    {% for tag in blogs['recipes'].tags %}
        <h2>{{ tag }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can also do `blogs.recipes.tags`

```
<div id=”blog-tags”>
    <!– Loops over all the tags used in Recipes blog –>
    {% for tag in blogs.recipes.tags %}
        <h2>{{ tag }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```